# CSS layout with header and colums top to bottom

Tags: css

Greets,

I'm currently working on a website and have stumbled upon some layout difficulties. What I want is a website with a header (fixed hight) and followed by three columns (left, middle, left). I want the columns to stretch from top to bottom. But when I set them to a 100% height, the page gets overflow from the static header on 140px. I have included an image of the page with lots of colors to show the divs (http://oi51.tinypic.com/974rqd.jpg).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: There are a number of ways to solve the problem, which has been discussed enough to have a name: the *Holy Grail*. Googling CSS Holy Grail will give you any number of approaches with different markup requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your problem:
http://www.cssplay.co.uk/layouts/three-column-layouts.html

Answer (score 0):

Set a background image that repeats vertically. Either one image for each section, or easier yet, a single image that contains the dividers of all 3 sections.

See [here](http://andreasviklund.com/files/demo/1024px/) for an example of this being done.

Comment: How would this solution do if the page where to be resized by the user (browser). With one image and the divs width decided on percentage wouldn't the image go off-scale?

Comment: Are the columns going to change width? I didn't see an indication of that in the original question. If the columns aren't fixed width then the solution won't work.

Comment: I am sorry, I should have specified my question better.